# How to obtain both Ad-Group and AdId for every conversion w/o using AdWords SDK?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-ads-api, adgroup

In our iOS app we use both Firebase and AdWords SDKs.
We use Firebase for app installs and in-app events and we use Adwords SDK for the sole purpose of pinging to AdWords on first app launch.
This ping triggers a pre-configured postback URL to our server.
This postback contains the Ad Group and the user’s Advertiser Identifier(AdId), thus allowing us to match the conversion's Ad-Group to a specific user in our database.
This procedure allows us to determine which Ad-Group is the most efficient.

BUT

On AdWords support page with the title [Track app conversions with the AdWords SDK or a server-to-server connection](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095881), right under the title appears the following text:

> On March 31, 2018, the AdWords SDK will be replaced as the main tool
>   for tracking conversions via SDK by Google Analytics for Firebase.

Which means we won’t be able to keep using AdWords SDK.

What other way is there to obtain both Ad-Group and AdId for each conversion? 
(We found that the data on BigQuery isn't liable enough so we can't use that.)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am in the same situation, trying to discern how to get this data from BigQuery with no luck, and no response from the Firebase team.

Comment: I didn't manage to find a solution and eventually, we didn't use firebase.